# Can the tar in our lungs from cigarettes be removed from our body after stopping smoking?

Tags: smoking, pulmonology, lungs

I have been smoking a lot of cigarettes these days and am concerned about my lungs. Can/will the tar in my lungs from cigarettes ever be removed?